タスクスケジューラのセキュリティオプションについて
ある共用PCのタスクスケジューラを用いて次のPowerShellを動かすSlack通知ツールを作成しています。
PowerShellの内容

共用PCでquery user /server:IPアドレスを実行してログイン状況を配列にする
配列からactiveになっているユーザー名を取得
予め作成していた連想配列からユーザー名に該当する人の名前を取得
その人がリモート接続していますという文章をSlackのwebhook URLに送信してあるチャンネルに通知させる

タスクスケジューラの設定は下記のとおりです。

全般のセキュリティオプション：ユーザーがログオンしているかどうかにかかわらず実行する、最上位の特権で実行する
トリガー条件：タスクの開始はユーザーセッションへの接続時で詳細設定は有効にチェック
操作：プログラムの開始はbatファイル
それ以外の設定：デフォルト

※batファイルはPowerShellを起動させるためのものでその際に-ExecutionPolicyはBypassとし、-WindowStyleはHiddenとしています
以上の構成で作成したタスクスケジューラを準備完了にした状態でリモート接続をおこなうとPowerShellが動きませんでした。
動かないことを確認したのちに、まずはbatファイルを直接ダブルクリックするとSlackに通知されることが確認できました。次に以下の修正を加え再リモート接続をしました

batファイルにメッセージボックスを表示させるコマンドを1行追加
PowerShellファイルにメッセージボックスを表示させるコマンドを追加

その結果、1は実行され、メッセージボックスが表示されましたがPowerShellは動かないことが判明しました。
そこで設定に問題があると考えて試しに、ユーザーがログオンしているかどうかではなく『ユーザーがログオンしているときのみ実行する』に変更し再々リモート接続をしました。
その結果、問題無くSlack通知まで動くことが確認できました。
以上から私の頭ではセキュリティオプションの設定が原因でPowerShellが動かないと考えているのですが、正直このタスクはユーザーがログオンしているかどうかにかかわらず実行されて欲しいです。
共用PCは私以外の利用者のアカウントも作成し使用されているため、私以外の誰かがリモート接続した段階でそれを検知してお知らせしてほしいためです。
以上の説明から、原因や修正方法等をご存じの方いないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

タスクスケジューラ設定の操作タブのところで、「プログラム/スクリプト」にBATファイルではなくパワーシェルの実行ファイルを指定し、引数にBATファイル内でPowerShellの引数に指定していた内容を入れてみてはどうでしょう？ あと設定タブの「タスクを強制終了する」にチェックを入れるのと、スクリプトで実行するプログラムの中でコンソール入出力を行わない(そうしたプログラムを使わないか何か工夫する)ようにした方が良いかもしれません。(セッション0の分離)サービスからexeを実行する方法 あるいはちょっと性質は違いますがこちらも参考に。C#サービスプログラムからリモートデスクトップ接続されているかどうかを判別したい
